# Overwrite Magento Adminhtml Store Switcher

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to edit the Magento Admin Products Grid Page - Need to edit the Store Switcher Block that shows there, But I'm not able to.

Have created a class in my module in a blocks folder:
[Name]_[Module]_Block_Store_Switcher

and my config.xml file has:

```
 <blocks>
 <adminhtml>
  <store>
    <rewrite>
        <switcher>[Name]_[Module]_Block_Store_Switcher</switcher>
    </rewrite> 
  </store>
 </adminhtml>
 </blocks>
```

Not able to identify what I'm doing wrong here - any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Correct code would look like this:

```
<blocks>
   <[Name]_[Module]>
      <class>[Name]_[Module]_Block</class>
   </[Name]_[Module]>
   <adminhtml>
    <rewrite>
     <store_switcher>[Name]_[Module]_Block_Switcher</store_switcher>
    </rewrite>
   </adminhtml>
</blocks>
```